# Will the SRT Viper be enough to win the Supercar Masters Series

Tags: real-racing-3

In the Supercar Masters Series I can chose (among others) between the SRT Viper GTS and an Audi R8 V10. Without any upgrades, the Viper performs best. But the Audi has a higher initial performance Rating.

Will upgrading the Viper be enough to finish this series, or will I not be able to reach the needed performance rating for the last races?

Is the Audi a competitive car in any other series which would make it more useful to upgrade the A8 now instead of the Viper?

Answer (score 2):

The Audi R8 is probably the best car you will drive up to that point. Fully upgraded it's better than the Nissan GT-R, much more stable during cornering and exiting. So I highly recommend you spend the money and get the Audi. It will also come in handy in the special series you unlock later.

Comment: I've by now bought and upgraded the Audi and can't really second that answer. While it might be faster on an empty track, winning a cup with it is harder than with a beefed up Viper. The Audis performance comes from really high traktion enabling late braking and early acceleration. Unfortunately, driving in a dense pack of other cars, this doesn't help much as other cars will block the optimal line entering and leaving a corner. The Viper has fas acceleration and top spead, clearing the pack on the straights after the corner.